# How to convert xmlhttprequest into string javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I just wounder how I can convert my xmlhttp request into a string that I then can perform operations on?

Say that I have the xmlhttp request in the variable "txt" like this (I'm opening a plain .html file for reading)

```
function handleXML(){
checkState(xmlhttp, function() {

var txt=xmlhttp.responseText + "";
txt.replace(/<&#91;^>&#93;*>/g, "");
//Convert txt into a string so that I can use it
});
}
```

**EDIT******************************************************************************************************************************************************************

Why I wonder is because the below function is not working with the argument "txt" but works fine with any other string argument

```
var buildName = "random";
var myvar = "";
myvar = lcs(txt, buildName);

function lcs(lcstest, lcstarget) {
  this.lcstest = lcstest;//Don't work
 this.lcstarget = lcstarget;
//But this works this.lcstest = "some random string"
 matchfound = 0;
 lsclen = lcstest.length;
  for(lcsi=0; lcsi<lcstest.length; lcsi++){
   lscos=0;
    for(lcsj=0; lcsj<lcsi+1; lcsj++){
     re = new RegExp("(?:.{" + lscos + "})(.{" + lsclen + "})", "i");
     temp = re.test(lcstest);
     re = new RegExp("(" + RegExp.$1 + ")", "i");
      if(re.test(lcstarget)){
       matchfound=1;
       result = RegExp.$1;
       break;
       }
     lscos = lscos + 1;
     }
     if(matchfound==1){return result; break;}
    lsclen = lsclen - 1;
   }
  result = "fgh";
  return result;
 }
```

Comment: `txt` should already be a string. What type is it?

Comment: @john - try this.lcstest = "" + lcstest; or try this.lcstest = new string(lcstest)

Answer (score 0):

No need to do any thing just have to assign the return value of replace function to variable itself will do your task.

```
txt = txt.replace(/<&#91;^>&#93;*>/g, "");
```

**EDIT**

You need to decalre you `var txt` out side handleXML function. to access the value of it in `lcs` function.

```
var txt;

function handleXML(){
checkState(xmlhttp, function() {

txt=xmlhttp.responseText + "";
txt.replace(/<&#91;^>&#93;*>/g, "");
//Convert txt into a string so that I can use it
});
}
```

**EDIT**

try `this.lcstest = "" + lcstest;`

or try

```
this.lcstest = new string(lcstest)
```

Comment: Please take another look, it is apparently not a string since the method that I'm calling is working with other strings but not with the xmlhttp request string. I have already checked and document.write(txt) works and it prints out the webpage fine. =)

Comment: Thats not the problem, if I do document.write(lcstest) inside the function lcs, it prints out everything that I'm reading in. And that webpage contains the word "random" and it should be returned by the function, but it is not, lcstest is not treated as a string by the function lcs, and I don't underastand why? :/